# Android Layout behavior not equal in different api levels

Tags: android

I have an activity with DrawerLayout connected to a Toolbar.  For the content of the same activity, I have a NestedScrollView that holds a bunch of items, as shown in the xml below:

activity_main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In activity_main, it includes app_bar_main, which contains a CoordinatorLayout with and AppbarLayout. app_bar_main also includes content_main with a NestedScrollView as shown below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.justinlee.whichpay.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <some other items.....>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Running the app on an AVD with API level 21 or above, the app works just fine. However, if I run it on an AVD with API level 20 or below, the app is not working in several ways:

1. I cannot click on the items on the Toolbar/Actionbar (ex. the ActionBarDrawerToggle on the left and the search icon on the right)
2. when I scroll it up, the NestedScrollView seems to overlap above on the Toolbar, instead of staying behind the Toolbar in normal situations, like the picture shown below:
   [image]

Here are what I have checked:

1. Made sure that all the layouts and/or the widgets used in the app are based on the support library.
2. Made sure that that the component tree items are in the right order, so Toolbar should stay above over the NestedScrollView

Does anyone have any idea about what is causing this problem
Greatly appreciated!